# dictionary to csv only yields in incomplete/incorrect data

Tags: python-3.x

trying to convert dictionary to csv

this is my dictionary:

```
order = {'company_name': 'FRIENDS',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-12-06', 'region': 'WEST'}
{'company_name': 'FLOWERS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-29', 'region': 'CENTRAL'}
{'company_name': 'SUNSHINE',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37414901860683000000', 'longitude': '103.94353973518100000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-08', 'region': 'EAST'}
{'company_name': 'CLOUDS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'}
{'company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH'}
```

i have tried:

```
csv_file = 'test.csv'
csv_columns = order.keys()
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in order:
            writer.writerow(order)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

the output only gives me multiple repeated of only 1 dataset

```
company_name,delivery_timeslot,latitude,longitude,status,date,region

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST
```

how do i go about resolving this? do i need to loop to iterate the data?

Comment: You are missing commas after each set of `{}` like this `{ }, { }, { }`, also it should be data here `writer.writerow(order)` instead of order.

Comment: actually your order is not a correct dictionary, probably if you encapsulate it in a list will it have different values, otherwise the keys/vaues are rewritten, hence you only have one record